# In-App Purchase wrong callback response type

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, in-app-purchase

i'm developing chrome extension with in-app purchases following next guide [URL](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap) .
I'm using next code in my chrome extension to call buy method:

```
/*****************************************************************************
 * Purchase an item
 *****************************************************************************/

function buyProduct(sku) {
    console.log("google.payments.inapp.buy", sku);
    google.payments.inapp.buy({
        parameters: {
            'env': "prod"
        },
        'sku': sku,
        'success': onPurchase,
        'failure': onPurchaseFailed
    });
}

function onPurchase(purchase) {
    console.log("onPurchase", purchase);
    var jwt = purchase.jwt;
    var cartId = purchase.request.cardId;
    var orderId = purchase.response.orderId;
    getLicenses();
}

function onPurchaseFailed(purchase) {
    console.log("onPurchaseFailed", purchase);
}
```

So when i called buyProduct(sku) purchase works fine and after purchase complete success(user clicked buy button in newly window provided by buy.js) I got failure callback with response object and checkoutOrderId property inside.
But it should be success event. Then check Google Payment account and see that purchase was completed.
Did anyone get the same error?

P.S.: send an email with problem description to Google support w8ing for the response.

Comment: i can check failure callback and check licenses there but it will be not right, i think

Comment: I see the same behavior. It would be great if you reported a bug perhaps on bugs.chromium.org

Comment: its pointless to report that bug. the Chrome team KNOWS this since at least several months ago because Im one of the people that reported it. there are many more major bugs with the webstore, I do not recommend using it. they do answer emails claiming they are looking at it, they arent. I ended up implementing stripe payments.

Comment: @ZigMandel can you share report bug link, please?

Comment: there isnt a link. you can't put it in chromium because the webstore is not part of Chromium. I have several support emails where google claims to be concerned. if you google the issue you will see old google group posts disussing this specific issue and workaround.